# Redshift max value from all tables in schema

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Thanks for taking the time to go through this!

I have a redshift cluster having multiple tables within a schema and all tables have a date field that says when a row was inserted into the table.
The name of the date field is same for every table.
ex:

```
1. Schema = public 
   table name = packages
   date field = timestamp
2. Schema = public 
   table name = binary ...
   date field = timestamp
```

I want to be able to iterate over all tables in the aforementioned schema and get the maximum of the date fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, "iterate over all tables" implies that this is not done purely in SQL.  So you need some layer to dynamically gather the list of all tables in the schema and loop on them.  This loop can find the max date for each OR create the SQL that will UNION ALL the information and produce the single max value.  I'd lean towards a loop that iterates each table as there are limits to how many tables can be addressed in a single SQL statement and the number of tables in a schema can be quite large.

Next decision is where to perform this loop.  This can be done externally to Redshift OR internally with a stored procedure.  I'd recommend that you do this externally as stored procedures are generally not the fastest way and come with restrictions that can limit what your code can do.  AWS gives you many tools that have strengths different than Redshift and combining them opens up many new options for what you can do with Redshift.  A Lambda function could be a good choice for performing this looping operation.  This does imply moving beyond (or augmenting) the approach of "I have a single JDBC/ODBC connection to my data systems". If you can make this transition the rewards are generally worth the effort.  If not you are looking at a stored procedure with the restrictions and speed it can provide.